# Drupal 7 preprocess single node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-preprocess

Is possible create a preprocess for single node?
For example, this is generic for all node:

```
function template_preprocess_node(&$variables) {}
```

we can also call something for single node?like this? i have tried various solution but not work.

```
function template_preprocess_node__mynode(&$variables) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would accomplish this using the same task that zen uses.

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {

  // Optionally, run node-specific preprocess functions, like
  // mytheme_preprocess_node_1().
  $function = __FUNCTION__ . '_' . $variables['node']->nid;
  if (function_exists($function)) {
    $function($variables, $hook);
  }
}
```

Thanks to the `if (function_exists($function))` bit you can simply implement a function for whichever specific nids you wish and it will find and execute them.  Just make sure that you pass in the `&$variables` parameter as a reference (with the `&`) or else none of your changes will find their way out of the function.